# Expo Tunnel not starting

Tags: react-native, expo, tunnel

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to start my react-native application using expo. But the tunnel option is not starting, it's displaying the

> Tunnel URL not found, falled back to LAN URL.

When I click to the tunnel tab, because it's not yet started. I waited for 2 hrs for it to start but it won't start. I run through different issues and questions asked but none solved my issue. [image: This is the image of the screen I've just stared at, for more than 2hrs]

**ENV:**

```
"expo": 36.0.0,
"expo-cli": 3.11.7
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find the solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202092/expo-does-not-show-the-tunnel-ready-message-anymore/66119276#66119276

Answer (score 0):

As of July 13, 2021, in my case Expo tunnel only works for the following environment:

- `expo-cli v. 3.11.9`
- `node v. 12.14.1`

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

I have not been able to make it work for any other version combinations. With this combination, everything works as expected without any other changes.

I have the latest version of `@expo/ngrok` installed globally.

The answer was found here: https://forums.expo.io/t/tunnel-url-not-found-falled-back-to-lan-url/34623/8