# Expo does not show the Tunnel ready message anymore

Tags: react-native, expo

I was using expo for some days. And after startups it always shown the `Tunnel ready` message as it should. I use `expo-cli` globally.

Somehow from today on that message does not appear anymore. It's not only the message. The Metro tunnel is actually not available.

Here the **expo diagnostics**:

```
  Expo CLI 3.21.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.16.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.14.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  4.0.0.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^37.0.12 => 37.0.12
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
      react-native-web: ~0.11.7 => 0.11.7
```

This is what Expo log tells me:

[image: Expo log]

There is nothing else happening. Even when I wait for a long time. No error or warning.

Maybe I use a buggy version of Expo? I also tried the latest version of expo without any change. And I completely deleted the `node_modules` folder completely. But no change. Also I was thinking about Windows blocking the 19001 port, so I restarted the PC. Not no change as well.

What could be the reason?

Hint: there is another very similar issue: [Expo Tunnel not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708676/expo-tunnel-not-starting) but actually in my case I not even get the error message which is even more strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually deploying to web and to Android still works. It's really just the message that is not printed out anymore. So maybe the `expo` version has updated and now does not print the

> Tunnel ready

message anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Tunnel support has to be installed in the local machine.

Go to the Left-hand side of the metro bundler web UI, and click on Tunnel. This should install the tunnel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just try disable windows firewall.